# How to prove $(s/t)\left(m/u+m'/u'\right)=(s/t)(m/u)+(s/t)(m'/u').$?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, fractions

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity 1. Let $T$ be nonempty multiplicative closed subset of $R$. Let $M$ be $R$-module. 
Define
$$T^{-1}M=\{m/t\mid m\in M,t\neq 0\}.$$
Define the addition and multiplication on $T^{-1}M$ as below.
$$m/t+m'/t'=(t'm+tm')/(tt')$$
$$(m/t)(m'/t')=(mm')/(tt').$$

Prove $$(s/t)\left(m/u+m'/u'\right)=(s/t)(m/u)+(s/t)(m'/u').$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
   (s/t)\left(m/u+m'/u'\right)
   &=& (s/t)\left((u'm+um')/(uu')\right)\\
   &=& ((uu')s+t(u'm+um'))/(tuu')\\
   &=& (uu's+tu'm+tum')/(tuu')\\
\text{I'm stuck here. I can't make the equation to this form.}\\
   &=& ((tu'sm)+(tusm'))/(tutu')\\
   &=& (sm)/(tu)+(sm')/(tu')\\
   &=& (s/t)(m/u)+(s/t)(m'/u')
   \end{eqnarray*}
So, I can't prove this question. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your line two; you need to multiply $(s/t)$ by $((u'm+um')/uu')$ and what you write is not that product. The argument goes as follows:

\begin{align*}
(s/t)(m/u+m'/u')&=(s/t)\big((u'm+um')/uu'\big)\\
&=\big((s(u'm+um'))/tuu'\big)\\
&=\big((su'm+sum')/tuu'\big)\\
&=(t/t)\big((su'm+sum')/tuu'\big)\\
&=\big((tsu'm+tsum')/ttuu'\big)\\
&=\big((tu'sm+tusm')/tutu'\big)\\
&=(sm/tu)+(sm'/tu')\\
&=(s/t)(m/u)+(s/t)(m'/u').
\end{align*}